Why are filters ordered in reverse to inclusion?
In topology (and set theory, etc.), filters are sets of subsets of some set $X$ with some conditions.
The pre-order on all filters on $X$ is defined on filters $F, G$ such that $F \le G \iff G \subseteq F$.
Why is the definition the reverse of inclusion? Are the reasons purely historic or is there some practical advantage?
